# google check out in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase, google-checkout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is it possible to intigrate google checkout with iphone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5521603/is-it-possible-to-intigrate-google-checkout-with-iphone)

how can i integrate google checkout in my iphone application.ebay has provided their iphone source and API key to integrate easily.but some forums are saying google checkout can done through UIWebview.is it possible to integrate GOOGLE Checkout in iphone Native Applications and interact with it?how can user get the conformation of payment

Comment: so, you mention `android` in a tag and you specify **iPhone SDK**? DO you know they are a little bit different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you got this working in iOS. Unless your app is for the sale of goods that aren't available via the app, it's unlikely your app will be approved under the following guidelines:

> 1. Purchasing and currencies
>
> 11.1 Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality
>   with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected
>
> 11.2
>
> Apps utilizing a system other than the In App Purchase API (IAP) to
>   purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be
>   rejected
>
> 11.3
>
> Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used
>   outside of the application will be rejected
>
> 11.4
>
> Apps that use IAP to purchase credits or other currencies must consume
>   those credits within the application
>
> 11.5
>
> Apps that use IAP to purchase credits or other currencies that expire
>   will be rejected
>
> 11.6
>
> Content subscriptions using IAP must last a minimum of 7 days and be
>   available to the user from all of their iOS devices
>
> 11.7
>
> Apps that use IAP to purchase items must assign the correct
>   Purchasability type
>
> 11.8
>
> Apps that use IAP to purchase access to built-in capabilities provided
>   by iOS, such as the camera or the gyroscope, will be rejected
>   11.9
>
> Apps containing "rental" content or services that expire after a
>   limited time will be rejected
>
> 11.10
>
> Insurance applications must be free, in legal-compliance in the
>   regions distributed, and cannot use IAP
>
> 11.11
>
> In general, the more expensive your app, the more thoroughly we will
>   review it
>
> 11.12
>
> Apps offering subscriptions must do so using IAP, Apple will share the
>   same 70/30 revenue split with developers for these purchases, as set
>   forth in the Developer Program License Agreement.
>
> 11.13
>
> Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions
>   to be used in the app, such as a “buy" button that goes to a web site
>   to purchase a digital book, will be rejected
>
> 11.14
>
> Apps can read or play approved content (specifically magazines,
>   newspapers, books, audio, music, and video) that is subscribed to or
>   purchased outside of the app, as long as there is no button or
>   external link in the app to purchase the approved content. Apple will
>   not receive any portion of the revenues for approved content that is
>   subscribed to or purchased outside of the app

Comment: `purchase content, functionality, or services in an app will be rejected`, you can use any other checkouts to purchase goods for example like groceries.

Comment: I didn't know that! I'll add to my answer.

Comment: @james : you both says google checkout is not possible.but how eBay payment is approved by apple?

Comment: I didn't say it wasn't possible, I'm just warning you that depending on how you structure your app, it may be rejected. Be aware of the guidelines.

Comment: will you please give the apple link for the info u took

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html